# Android Studio Java getSystemService Error

Tags: java, android-studio

FYI, it's been less than 2 months I started learning java and so I'm a very beginner.
I'm trying to figure out how to apply vibration when users click on choices. But, getSystemService is red for some reason. What did I do wrong and what do I need to modify?
(I imported vibration and wrote uses-permission for vibration in manifest xml.)
I tried what other people suggested but whatever I tried getSystemService is always red...
Here is the code I have:

```
  public void hospital1select1() {
      h1.character.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      h1.text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      showButton();
      h1.choice1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      h1.choice4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
      h1.choice2.setText("");
      h1.choice3.setText("");

      h1.choice1.findViewById(R.id.choice1);
      h1.choice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view){
  Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator)
  getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
              vibrator.vibrate(400);
          }
      });

      c2 = "h110a";
      c3 = "h110b";
  }
```

Comment: try removing the `*` so just `getSystemService(...)`

Comment: oh that was just to bold it but I guess it doesn't bold the letters here. But thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: Have you tried importing the static method `getSystemService` where does it come from?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it exactly, but when I put static, h1 goes all red.. I'm still learning the basics so I have a hard time understanding..

Answer (score 0):

#### Step 1

Add permission in `Manifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

#### Step 2

Add these three lines as an import on top of your java_file e.g. `MainActivity.java`

```
import android.os.VibrationEffect
import android.os.Vibrator
import android.os.VibratorManager
```

#### Step 3

In you `onClickListener`, copy/paste this

```
Vibrator vibrator;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
    VibratorManager vibratorManager = (VibratorManager) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_MANAGER_SERVICE);
    vibrator = vibratorManager.getDefaultVibrator();
} else {
    vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
}
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    vibrator.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(400, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
else
    vibrator.vibrate(400);
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested but it still shows getSystemService in red..

Comment: Can you show that image as a Screenshot

Comment: I don't know how to add image here but when put "h1." in front of "getSystemService" and the red line went away. Since I put h1 in front of all the codes, I thought I should try putting it there too. Not sure if it's correct though.

However, I have another question. Where should I add the vibration code if I want to have a vibration when I click on a choice??

Comment: I didn't get `h1`, anyway, you can edit your question and can add image at the end of your question. Yes, you can place this vibration in a function and can call it on `Choice` selection / click listener